# Install floor tile or tile-board first?

Tags: bathroom, walls, tile

We are updating a small basement bathroom.  We agree on the style and materials, but not exactly on the method of installation.  The idea is to put tile down on the floor, and use tile-board for the walls.  Do we install the floor tile first, or the tile-board first?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floor first.

Tile.  Cut out the the bottom of the drywall so that the tile can sit underneath it.

Throw some cardboard on top of your tile, sit tile board on tile and put it up.  Pull out cardboard.  Caulk the gap.  You are done and everything looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The general consensus is that for the purpose of quality, it's best to do the floor first.  But, a professional tiler will do the walls first most of the time, so they can get the job done faster.  After you do the floor, you can't do the walls until the floor sets.

Answer (score 0):

Seems kinda like washing a car....from the top down.  Once that NEW pretty tile is on the floor, you will have to protect it for the remainder of the project.  Dirty boots, dropped tools, grout drips all will have to be guarded against to avoid damage.

Comment: A roll of contractor's paper or a few sheets of taped down cardboard will go a long way towards alleviating all of the concerns you list.

Comment: Yeah, but mess has a way to find it's way through.